# "SQL Server 2008 Management Studio failed to load" after upgrading to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssms

I upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 and since then the SQL Server 2008 SP1 Management Studio Package is broken. Whenever I start it, it just shows the message "Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load". and closes again immediately after clicking OK.

SQL server itself is still running fine, I can still access it from my web app.

Any idea what might be going wrong or how I can fix this? Would a re-install help? I was careful to update SQL Server 2008 to SP1, so it was supposed to be compatible with Windows 7.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you re-install  sp1?

Comment: Yes, and that seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!